# Cross-validation ($3$-fold) for optimizing ($C$, $\gamma$) in RBF-SVM

Tags: classification, svm, cross-validation

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a training set which will feed a **binary SVM** with **RBF kernel**. $\mathcal{X}$ consists of $10$ positive examples and $100$ negative examples. I am interested in optimizing the parameters of the above SVM, i.e. the well-known parameters $C$, $\gamma$.

What I am doing now, is to partition the above set, $\mathcal{X}$, into a $70\%$ training subset, and a $30\%$ testing subset, and carry out a grid-search ($3$-fold cross-validation) in order to obtain the best pair $(C_{opt},\gamma_{opt})$.

That is, $\mathcal{X}$ is partitioned such that the following three subsets are created
$$
\mathcal{X}_{1},\:\mathcal{X}_{2},\:\mathcal{X}_{3},
$$
and hold, respectively, $4$, $4$, and $3$ positive samples (randomly chosen). Moreover, each subset also consists of a number of negative samples ($34$, $33$, and $33$, respectively), randomly chosen, as well.

The cross-validation procedure, though, does not seem to obtain the optimal parameters.

What would you suggest me to do? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One issue you are likely having is with your unbalanced dataset, only 10% of your examples are positive.  You could address this issue through resampling or class weighting your examples.  Some of the methods mentioned in these links may help:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.96.9248&rep=rep1&type=pdf

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html

[SVM for unbalanced data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94295/svm-for-unbalanced-data)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736125/how-do-you-handle-data-imbalance-in-svm

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Besides the information I could get from your links, do you think that I could just use fewer negative samples (e.g. $70$ instead of $100$)?

Comment: If you do that then you'll lose the information those 30 samples could have provided your classifier!  What if they are the important 30, and the other 70 are random noise?

Comment: Yes, I see... I think that weighted-class SVM could do the job. But, concerning the cross-validation described above, what do you think? Is there any mistake?

Comment: No, your crossvalidation procedure looks fine to me.  I think your main challenge is your small and unbalanced data set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your suggestions seem helpful, I'll wait though for other users too.

Comment: Also, check the other link I added for a more thorough review of this situation